# Delaunay Triangulation Connectivity List and parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

The order of the ConnectivityList of a modified DelaunayTriangulation is changing if using inside a parfor loop. The following code can be tested to see this. (on Matlab2014R)

```
clear all
clc
dx=0.25;
x=0:dx:1;
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,x);
x=reshape(x,numel(x),1);
y=reshape(y,numel(y),1);
%creation of the triangulation
tri_mesh=delaunayTriangulation(x,y);
%=== The 2 orders are the same ===%
parfor i=1:1
    tri_mesh.ConnectivityList(1:5,:)
end
for i=1:1
    tri_mesh.ConnectivityList(1:5,:)
end

%we modify the triangulation
tri_mesh_ex=tri_mesh;
Vert=[-0.2 -0.2 ; -0.2 0];
tri_mesh_ex.Points(end+(1:length(Vert)),:)=Vert;
tri_mesh_ex.ConnectivityList(1:5,:)
%=== The orders are different ===%
parfor i=1:1
    tri_mesh_ex.ConnectivityList(1:5,:)
end
for i=1:1
    tri_mesh_ex.ConnectivityList(1:5,:)
end
%=== solution of the problem ===%
Connectivity_list=tri_mesh_ex.ConnectivityList(1:5,:);
parfor i=1:1
    Connectivity_list
end
```

The ConnectivityList of the 1st DelaunayTriangulation in the parfor or for loop is the same while it changes if the DelaunayTriangulation is modified (2nd DelaunayTriangulation).

To get the correct order, the ConnectivityList must be stored in another variable before being used inside the parfor loop.

Result of matlab:
[image: Matlab Run]

Comment: So just to be clear, when you replace `parfor` with `for`, you get different results?  Also, `return x_new, y_new` is invalid MATLAB syntax.  There are no return statements other than simply exiting a function.  All you have to do is assign the output variable to something.

Comment: From the code I see here, everything seems fine. Please try to create a [mcve] which allows us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @rayryeng thank you for your answer. The "return" was just a pseudocode so you know which variables are returned (sorry for the missunderstanding).

Comment: @Daniel thank you for you answer too. I followed your advice and tried to create an example. After performing some tests, I found that the problem is on the DelaunayTriangulation object. I notice the following weird thing:
- displaying the connectivityList in the for or in the parfor loop doesn't display the same connectivityList
- saving the data in a .mat, clearing all and loading the same data destroys the previous behavior (???????)
- trying to create an example leads to a good result.
Since the triangulation is modified I will look if the problem comes from there.
Have you ever seen that?

Comment: @Daniel I had an example in the description.

Comment: Is your code intended to modify the `DelaunayTriangulation` object within the loop?

Comment: You have an example in your question, but it is not verifiable because we can not run the code. The input arguments are missing.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I answered you before editing the post. I have to modify the triangulation during the code, but not inside the loop. I know that the objects cannot be modified if we are using parfor. Thank you very much for your advice of giving an example. It allows me to detect the problem. By the way, I have the warning:"The entire array is a broadcast variable"

Comment: @Kil.Th: What should the inserted code demonstrate? The output is as I would expect.

Comment: @Daniel Well, not in my matlab: the ordering of the 2 last displays is changing. And the ordering is directly connected to the indices i (corresponding to the triangle i) in my code (not in the example). I don't know if this behavior is a bug or done on purpose.

Comment: I see a different order in the last three outputs, but that is what I expect as you inserted a point. Please put the output you are getting into the question.

Comment: @Daniel I just upload the picture. The three first displays are the same, while the 4th one (parfor) differs from the 3 first and the 5th one. The last display is the "trick" to solve this. Don't you have the same behavior?

Comment: From what I see here, that is a bug. I recommend to contact the support, there might be a bugfix available.